# How to use text from capturing groups in Google Docs regex replace?

Tags: google-docs, regex

I'm trying to match certain text and then replace with the text plus some extra characters. Minimal example text:

`#10 Oranges. These are citrus fruits`

Desired output:

`#10 Oranges.
These are citrus fruits`

Regex: `(#\d{1,2}[^.]*\.)\s*`

Replace with: `$1\n`

(I have `Match using regular expressions` checked)

The regex successfully matches `#10 Oranges.`. However the numbered backreference doesn't replace the text with the capture group but just goes in literally (literal output is `$1\n`). I have also tried using a backslash for the numbered backreference `\1` and the result is the same.

Is there something I'm missing? How do I reinsert matched text in google docs using regular expressions?

Comment: The docs now explicitly state: `Note: Capture groups only work with Google Sheets.` See https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754#regular_expressions

Answer (score 9):

Little hacky, but it doesn't require an extra add on script and will likely cover 99% of your use cases.  You can still use capture groups with `RegexReplace` and reference in the replace text with `$1` or `$2`.  Just split up your regex into two capture groups and concatenate with a random (infrequently used) character like `~`.  Then you can take the entire returned value from that and replace `~` with a newline:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(#\d{1,2}[^.]*\.)(\s*)","$1~$2"),"~",CHAR(10))
```

[image: screenshot]

For more info on the regex syntax used in google sheets, see the [re2 spec](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

Comment: the question is about Docs, not Sheets, as far as I understand.

Comment: I came here looking for a Sheets answer, and this is exactly what I was looking for!  +1 from me.

Answer (score 7):

## Short answer

Instead of using the built-in find and replace function use [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start) or an add-on.

## Explanation

On the Find and Replace feature of Google Documents, the Replace part doesn't work with regular expressions and it doesn't work either with the `replaceText()` method from the Documents Service in Google Apps Script fortunately JavaScript replace method works.

To learn the very basics to create a simple script, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

### Code

This code is an adaptation of the one included in the reference

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  for (var i=0; i<paragraphs.length; i++) {
    var text = paragraphs[i].getText();
    paragraphs[i].replaceText(".*", 
       text.replace(/(\d{1,2}[^.]*\.)\s*/gi, '$1\n') );
  }
}
```

## References

- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33528920/1595451) by Mogsdad to [replaceText() RegEx “not followed by”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968419/replacetext-regex-not-followed-by)

Comment: I'll consider looking into this, but is the fact that replace doesn't work with regex a bug? According to this documentation, it looks like it should work: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754#regular_expressions (see the section `Replace with regular expressions`)

Answer (score 6):

As stated by [user](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/12334/user) in the comments

[Note: Capture groups only work with Google Sheets.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754#regular_expressions)

Answer (score 1):

As stated previously, you can't use regular expressions or capture groups in the replace field with Google Docs. But here's an easy workaround for a portion of your specific case.

To replace `\n` with a newline, just copy and paste an actual newline from your document to the replace field. It will show as a blank space in the field, but the newline is preserved and will replace all `\n`.

It's useful for example to replace double newlines `\n\n` or space before newline  `\n` with only one newline.